# How to find Sharepoint 2013 CSS Classes?

Tags: css, sharepoint, ms-office

I'm currently getting familiar with CSS to redesign some SharePoint sites.
My question now is: How can I find the classes I need for that ? 
Litte examples that I found on the internet and used:

"ms-rtestate-field" for styling a SharePoint list
".ms-promlink-header" for enabling multiple rows for the promoted links webpart

I wasn't able to find these classes in the Source before adding the CSS.
So where did the creators find those classes ?
The SharePoint documentation didnt help me, but this could be due to my lack of my knowledge and understanding of css.

Thanks in advance

Comment: this requires access to the server am I right ? if yes, this is not an option. sorry if I didnt clarify this.

Comment: it does not require access to the server. Use this after your webapp URL: /_layouts/15/1043/styles/Themable/corev15.css (change the 1043 to your locale)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it was indeed my fault that I wasn't able to find any classes using the F12 Dev Toolbar. It works fine now with the pointing tool and I can find classes easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to customize the display of SharePoint, redefine CSS class, in SharePoint 2013, there is **Color Palette**.

Microsoft have created a tools to manage color palette : [SharePoint Color Palette Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38182)

With this you can customize the color of you sharepoint site easily.

And you can find a lot of documentation about this tools ;-)